# AWS Route 53 - DNS Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have been working on getting my DNS to work properly for the past few days. Here is how I have it setup:

(I am using GoDaddy existing domain)

- I setup a Hosted Zone called ironblu.com
- I grabbed the NS from the hosted zone and changed them on the GoDaddy dashboard
- I added in 2 records to the Hosted Zone
- A record
- blank nname - A IPV4 - Value 52.2.188.143 (My EC2 Elastic IP)
- Another A record (I tried * already and same result) with www
- A IPV4 - Value 52.2.188.143
- And the SOA record in the hosted zone

Here are the results from dnswatch:

```
Searching for ironblu.com. A record at H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. [198.97.190.53] ...took 93 ms
Searching for ironblu.com. A record at f.gtld-servers.net. [192.35.51.30] ...took 1 ms
Searching for ns-1668.awsdns-16.co.uk. A record at E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. [192.203.230.10] ...took 1 ms
Searching for ns-1668.awsdns-16.co.uk. A record at nsa.nic.uk. [156.154.100.3] ...took 10 ms
Searching for ns-1668.awsdns-16.co.uk. A record at g-ns-336.awsdns-16.co.uk. [205.251.193.80] ...took 8 ms
Searching for ironblu.com. A record at ns-1668.awsdns-16.co.uk. [205.251.198.132] ...took 159 ms

A record found: 52.2.188.143
Domain  Type    TTL Answer
ironblu.com.    NS  172800  ns-1267.awsdns-30.org.
ironblu.com.    NS  172800  ns-1668.awsdns-16.co.uk.
ironblu.com.    NS  172800  ns-42.awsdns-05.com.
ironblu.com.    NS  172800  ns-946.awsdns-54.net.
ironblu.com.    A   300 52.2.188.143
```

---

The issue is that when you visit ironblu.com or www.ironblu.com it just redirects me to the public DNS on my EC2 instance which is http://ec2-52-2-188-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

Am I missing something? I wish that my domain name stays in the URL rather than acting as a redirect.

Thanks for the help in advance! I hope I provided enough information!

Comment: The redirect is happening at your web server and has nothing to do with Route53. What web server are you using? You need to configure the web server to be aware of the domain it is serving.

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS and using a wordpress install.

Comment: Mark B. This has been resolved. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a DNS problem, your DNS is operating as expected.

Instead, this redirect is being done by your webserver or application. If you are using Wordpress for example, it will keep the domain it was installed with and redirect to that when accessed.

Comment: Perfect, that must be it then. I am using wordpress and windows server 2012 R2. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Never mind this was it. Did a little google fu and put in these variables into my wp-config.php file:
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');